# Where was “In This Corner of the World" funded?

Tags: anime-production, in-this-corner-of-the-world

*In This Corner of the World* (or *Kono Sekai no Katasumi ni*) was announced recently to be funded for an anime adaption.

However, I can't find the original source of the crowdfunding campaign. I'd like to be able to see their pitch, budgets and other interesting information that they've likely provided to potential funders.

[The official website](http://www.konosekai.jp/) doesn't seem to mention it either.

Where was the anime funded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Kono Sekai no Katasumi ni* crowdfunding project was hosted by Makuake](https://www.makuake.com/project/konosekai/), a crowdfunding platform managed by CyberAgent Inc.

It [opened on March 9, 2015 with a goal of 20,000,000 yen in 80 days](http://otakumode.com/news/54fd6553413196a05a8784ef/Anime-Feature-%E2%80%98Kono-Sekai-no-Katasumi-ni%E2%80%99-Begins-Crowdfunding-Original-Work-by-Fumiyo-Kono-Directed-by-Sunao-Katabuchi?lang=en) but has hit 36,224,000 yen (181%). It closed and is no longer accepting pledges.

The animation studio is MAPPA, which created *Sakamichi no Apollon*, and the producer is Genco.

To check for other anime and live-action film crowdfunding projects you might be interested in participating in, the [listing is here](https://www.makuake.com/discover/categories/film/).